# Environment variable not been binding in spring boot application startup

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

My application is trying to connect with Mongo DB 3.2. My connection URL contains a system environment variable. The issue is, system env variable  not been binding when application startup.
it's shows

```
 Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ${mongo_ipaddress3}: unknown error
```

But when I try with IP address instead of putting env variable it's working perfectly

my application-qa.yml

> data:
>       mongodb:
>           uri: mongodb://${mongo_username}:${secret_lass_qa_mongo_password}@${mongo_ipaddress1},${mongo_ipaddress2},${mongo_ipaddress3},${mongo_ipaddress4}/${mongo_dbname}
>           database: ${mongo_dbname}

Comment: Are you certain that there environment variables are being set? I hope you have tried to verify by printing all environment variables on app startup. Also you can edit your answer to format config yml correctly.

Comment: Yes I printed all environment variables and values are there

Comment: Just a hunch. Can you print value of `data.mongodb.uri`. Why is Unknown host coming for `{mongo_ipaddress3}` and not `{mongo_ipaddress1}`? Maybe only some variables are getting resolved.

Comment: @Archit The issue in the password field in the connection string. it has passed empty value when data binding hence whole connection string not been initialized and break the connections string

Comment: Oh great to know that it is solved!